# Two-site fermion system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, fermions

I've to study a two-site fermion system with hamiltonian
$$H=\sum_{\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow}[\epsilon_1 c^+_{1\sigma}c_{1\sigma}+\epsilon_2 c^+_{2\sigma}c_{2\sigma}+w(c^+_{1\sigma}c_{2\sigma}+c^+_{2\sigma}c_{1\sigma})].$$

I've proven that this hamiltonian preserves the number of particles.
When $N=0$ or $N=4$ there is only possible state, respectively using occupation number rapresentation: $|0\rangle$ and $|1111\rangle$.

1. Are these state eigenstates? How can i calculate their energy?

I diagonalized the Hamiltonian. The new creation and annihilation operators that I found, which preserve the commutation rules being a canonical transformation, what do they represent? I write the Hamiltonian diagonalized
$$H=\sum_{k,\sigma}\epsilon_ka^+_{k\sigma}a_{k\sigma} $$

2. If I apply $a^+_{1\uparrow}$ to the vacuum state, I actually get a fermion in state one with spin up or I get the fermions related to the various $c^+_{i,\sigma}$ associated with the creation operator  $a^+_{1\uparrow}=\sum_iU^+_{i1}c^+_{i\uparrow}$ with $U$ the matrix of normalized eigenvectors of the basis change.

Sorry for maybe very stupid question

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Are these state eigenstates? How can i calculate their energy?
```

Act Hamiltonian on the states $\vert 00,00\rangle $ and  $\vert 11,11\rangle $. The 4 number denotes occupation for site 1 spin-up, site 1 spin-down, site 2 spin-up, and site 2 spin-down:

$$
H=\sum_{\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow}[\epsilon_1 c_{1\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{1\sigma}
+ \epsilon_2 c_{2\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{2\sigma}
+ w(c_{1\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{2\sigma}+c_{2\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{1\sigma})].
$$

$$
  H \vert 00, 00\rangle = 0 \vert 00, 00\rangle.
$$
The state $\vert 00, 00\rangle$ is a eigen state of $H$ with eigen value $0$.

Next, examine $H \vert 11, 11\rangle$:

\begin{align}
\epsilon_1 c^\dagger_{1\uparrow}c_{1\uparrow} \vert 11, 11\rangle & = \epsilon_1 \vert 11, 11\rangle \\
\epsilon_2 c^\dagger_{2\uparrow}c_{2\uparrow} \vert 11, 11\rangle &= \epsilon_2 \vert 11, 11\rangle\\
w c^\dagger_{1\uparrow}c_{2\uparrow} \vert 11, 11\rangle &=w c^\dagger_{1\uparrow}
 \vert 11, 01\rangle = 0 \vert 11, 01\rangle = 0\vert 11, 11\rangle;\\
w c^\dagger_{2\uparrow}c_{1\uparrow} \vert 11, 11\rangle &=w c^\dagger_{2\uparrow}
 \vert 01, 11\rangle = 0 \vert 01, 11\rangle = 0\vert 11, 11\rangle;
\end{align}
The last two terms vanish, due to exclusion of fermion $c^\dagger\vert 1\rangle = 0 $.

Adding the cases for spin-down, we have
$$
H \vert 11, 11\rangle = (\epsilon_1+\epsilon_1+ \epsilon_2+\epsilon_2+0+0+0+0) \vert 11, 11\rangle =2 (\epsilon_1+ \epsilon_2) \vert 11, 11\rangle.
$$
The state $\vert 11, 11\rangle$ is eigen state of eigen value $2 (\epsilon_1+ \epsilon_2)$.

```
The basis changed
```

Writing the Hamitonian in matrix form:

$$
\sum_{\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow}
\begin{bmatrix} c_{1\sigma}^\dagger & c_{2\sigma}^\dagger \\ \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
  \epsilon_1 & w \\
  w & \epsilon_2 
 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} c_{1\sigma} \\ c_{2\sigma}  \end{bmatrix} 
$$
To diagonlize the Hamitonian, by an unitary matrix
$$
U =\begin{bmatrix} 
  \cos \frac{\theta}{2} & \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \\
  -\sin \frac{\theta}{2} & \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
 \end{bmatrix};\,\,\, 
U^T =\begin{bmatrix} 
  \cos \frac{\theta}{2} & -\sin \frac{\theta}{2} \\
  \sin \frac{\theta}{2} & \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\tan\theta = \frac{2 \,w}{\epsilon_2 - \epsilon_1}$. The Hamiltonian will become diagonal by $U^T H U$. In the following process.

$$
\sum_{\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow}
\begin{bmatrix} c_{1\sigma}^\dagger & c_{2\sigma}^\dagger \\ \end{bmatrix} 
\mathbf{U} \mathbf{U^T}
\begin{bmatrix} 
  \epsilon_1 & w \\
  w & \epsilon_2 
 \end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{U} \mathbf{U^T}
\begin{bmatrix} c_{1\sigma} \\ c_{2\sigma}  \end{bmatrix}
=\sum_{\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow}
\begin{bmatrix} a_{1\sigma}^\dagger & a_{2\sigma}^\dagger \\ \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
  \lambda_1 & 0 \\
  0 & \lambda_2 
 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} a_{1\sigma} \\ a_{2\sigma}  \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\lambda_{1, 2} = \frac{\epsilon_2+\epsilon_1}{2}\mp \sqrt{\left(\frac{\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1}{2}\right)^2 + w^2}$. The new bases:
$$ \tag{1}
 \begin{bmatrix} a_{1\sigma} \\ a_{2\sigma}  \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
  \cos \frac{\theta}{2} & -\sin \frac{\theta}{2} \\
  \sin \frac{\theta}{2} & \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} c_{1\sigma} \\ c_{2\sigma}  \end{bmatrix}
$$

The Hamiltonian with new bases is diagonal
$$
H=\sum_{\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow}[\lambda_1 a_{1\sigma}^\dagger\,a_{1\sigma}
+ \lambda_2 a_{2\sigma}^\dagger\,a_{2\sigma}.
$$

Show in the equation (1), the new basis $a_1$ and $a_2$ mixed the site $1$ and $2$, but didn't mixed the spin states.
\begin{align}
a_{1\sigma} & = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\, c_{1\sigma} - \sin\frac{\theta}{2} \, c_{2\sigma};\\
a_{2\sigma} & = \sin\frac{\theta}{2}\, c_{1\sigma} + \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \, c_{2\sigma};
\end{align}

```
Appendix
```

1. Diagonal of  2x2 symmetry matrix, by finding its eigen vectors:
   $$ \tag{A1}
    \mathbf{A} =
   \begin{bmatrix} 
     a & c \\
     c & b
    \end{bmatrix};
   \,\,\,\text{ eigen vector }\,\, 
   \begin{bmatrix} 
     a & c \\
     c & b
    \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix} 
     x \\
     y
    \end{bmatrix}
   = \lambda
   \begin{bmatrix} 
     x \\
     y
    \end{bmatrix};
   $$
   First find its eigen values, by solving determinant equation $\Vert \mathbf{A} - \lambda \mathbf{I} \Vert = 0$
   The quadratic equation render two roots (eigenvalues) for $\lambda$
   $$\tag{A2}
   \lambda_{+, -} = \frac{a+b}{2}\pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2 + c^2}
   $$
   Substitue Eq. (A2) into Eq. (A1) to find the ratio between $x:y$

\begin{align}
   & (a-\lambda) x + c y = 0;\\
\text{Let }   & \,\,\,x = c; \,\,\, y = \lambda -a; \\
\text{Normalization } &\,\,\, N = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 4 \cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\
\text{Define } & \,\,\,\tan\theta = \frac{c}{(b-a)/2}.
\end{align}

The eigen vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
  x \\
  y
 \end{bmatrix};
= \begin{bmatrix} 
  \cos \frac{\theta}{2} \\
  -\sin \frac{\theta}{2}
 \end{bmatrix};
\,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,
\begin{bmatrix} 
  \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \\
  \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
 \end{bmatrix};
$$
The two eigen vectors corresponding to $\lambda_{\pm}$ are mutual orthogonal

These tqo eigen vectors form the column of the unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}$
$$
 \mathbf{U} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
  \cos \frac{\theta}{2} & \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \\
  -\sin \frac{\theta}{2} & \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

2. Non-eigen state

\begin{align}
H &\vert 11,10\rangle  \\
= & \sum_{\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow}[\epsilon_1 c_{1\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{1\sigma}
+ \epsilon_2 c_{2\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{2\sigma}
+ w(c_{1\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{2\sigma}+c_{2\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{1\sigma})] 
\vert 11,10\rangle
\end{align}

The terms:
\begin{align}
 c_{1\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{1\sigma} \,\vert 11,10\rangle &= 1\vert 11,10\rangle;\text{ for both spins;} \\
c_{2\uparrow}^\dagger\,c_{2\uparrow}\, \vert 11,10\rangle &= 1\vert11,10\rangle;\\
c_{2\downarrow}^\dagger\,c_{2\downarrow}\, \vert 11,10\rangle &= 0\vert11,10\rangle;\\
c_{1\sigma}^\dagger\,c_{2\sigma}\, \vert 11,10\rangle &= 0; \text{ due to the term } c_{1\sigma}^\dagger\\
c_{2\downarrow}^\dagger\,c_{1\downarrow})\, \vert 11,10\rangle &= 1 \vert 10,11\rangle;
\end{align}

Put the above results all together:
\begin{align}
H \vert 11,10\rangle  =&
 \,\left( 2\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 +0+0+0+0\right)\,\vert 11,10\rangle
+ \,w \, \vert 10,11\rangle\\
 = & \,\left( 2\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 \right)\,\vert 11,10\rangle
+ \,w \, \vert 10,11\rangle
\end{align}

Comment: Thankyou very much

1)Please can you tell the method you have used to get that $U$.
Because i have the same eigenvalues. Tell me the method so i search for it and study

So the action of the new operator $a$ is both in 1 and 2 site.
2) If I want to calculate the energy of a state with N=3, for example |11,10>, how can i do? This state is not an eigenstate of H

Comment: I edited the answer including your comment in the appendix. Let me know if you had further questions.